# Does some textbook on probability use a particular way (described here) of accomplishing the segue into continuous distributions?

Tags: textbooks, probability

Imagine an introductory probability course that assumes the students have had first-year calculus and understand mathematical reasoning. At some point in such a course has explicated several families of discrete probability distributions, including the binomial distribution as the number of "successes" needed to get a specified non-random number of trials, and the negative binomial distribution as the number of failures before a specified non-random number of successes. Then one develops the Poisson distribution as a limit of binomial distributions with the expected number of successes remaining constant as the number of trials grows and the probability of success on each trial decreases, being inversely proportional to the number of trials.

One reaches a point in the exposition where to different Poisson-distributed random variables correspond to different subsets of the line, the expected value being $\mu$ times the measure of the subset, where $\mu$ is the same for all such subsets, and these random variables are independent when their corresponding subsets are essentially disjoint, and otherwise dependent and positively correlated.

At this point all probability distributions one has dealt with are **discrete**.

It seems that in **conventional** textbooks, one does not go from there do dealing with **particular continuous** probability distributions until one has dealt with continuous distributions in **general**, stating that they have continuous cumulative distribution functions, and in absolutely continuous cases, are characterized by a density function, the value of whose integral over a set is the probability assigned to that set.

But alternatively, suppose one has not yet done what is described in the paragraph above, but one has done what is described in the paragraph before that.

One can then let $T$ be the time until the first Poisson arrival after time $0$ and let $N_t$ be the number of arrivals before time $t,$ and observe this:
$$
\Pr(T>t) = {} \, \underbrace{\Pr( N_t=0) = \frac{(\mu t)^0 e^{-\mu t}}{0!}}_\text{This part has already been established.} \,= e^{-\mu t}.
$$
From there, it is easy to show that
$$
\Pr(T\in S) = \int_S e^{-\mu t} \big( \mu\, dt\big).
$$

Then one is dealing with a continuous distribution without having done what I reported to be done in conventional textbooks.

This has pedagogical advantages, upon which I may remark in comments if anybody cares.

**My question is** whether there is some published textbook that makes this kind of transition from discrete to continuous **without** first treating continuous distributions in general?

Comment: "Introductory" probability course that takes a measure-theoretic perspective? For students coming fresh from first-year calculus and mathematical reasoning? What??? Dear lord, I hope no students have to actually suffer through such a thing... that's like trying to teach differentiation right after a student learns about slope.

Comment: @JustinSkycak : I didn't say it takes a measure-theoretic perspective. No knowledge of calculus beyond the first year need be assumed.

Comment: @JustinSkycak : I've rephrased the question to avoid the particular misunderstanding that you indicated. This in no sense takes a measure-theoretic approach.

Comment: @JustinSkycak: I am currently teaching a second-year undergraduate probability course in which the measure theoretic basics are covered (the students simultaneously see them in greater depth in a real analysis course). These are ordinary math undergrads in Spain. This is a quite standard thing in countries like Spain, Italy, France, England (and surely many others). What I teach loosely corresponds with the first seven chapters of the book of Grimmett-Stirzaker.

Comment: @JustinSkycak : Based on your comment, I can't help but suspect that you think that if I use a little bit of terminology usually used heavily in measure theory, that that means I intend to carefully develop the theory of Lebesgue measure in the course. But it is easy to understand that the "measure" of an interval is its length, and the "measure" of a union of disjoint interval is the sum of their lengths, and the measure of a set is zero if it's smaller than all non-negative numbers, without making the least attempt to explain any general theory of measure.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't believe you intend to carefully develop the theory of Lebesgue measure in the course, just that your approach loosely comes from the perspective of measure theory. But I do believe that lots of beginning math students who are encountering probability for the first time are going to find this approach far more challenging to follow as compared to the conventional approach which is less theoretical and relies on far less prerequisite knowledge.

Comment: @JustinSkycak, I think you are exaggerating the difficulty of the approach sketched by Michael Hardy.  In fact there is a well-known implementation of this idea that's not merely elementary; it is [radically elementary](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464444/28128) :-)

Comment: @JustinSkycak : Read it again. You say it "loosely comes from the perspective of measure theory." That is nowhere near the truth and I don't know why anyone would think that. My guess is that when I referred to "the measure of the set" and used a couple of other terms that you associate with measure theory, that set off alarms in your head. But if you digest what the question actually says, you will realize that this does not rely on anything in measure theory.

Answer (score 0):

> One reaches a point in the exposition where to different Poisson-distributed random variables correspond to different subsets of the line.

I don't understand how you are supposed to "reach" this point, but assuming you did, the object you have at hand is an uncountably infinite collection of coupled random variables. This is much more complicated than a single continuous random variable, both to grasp intuitively and to construct rigorously (which is why the Poisson process on the real line is usually constructed starting with an infinite sequence of i.i.d. exponential waiting times).

Note that if you just have a countable collection of independent coin flips (and what you are doing is clearly more difficult), this is already equivalent to the construction of Lebesgue measure and trivially allows to construct continuous distributions.

Comment: $$ \text{begin quote} $$ I don't understand how you are supposed to "reach" this point, but assuming you did, the object you have at hand is an uncountably infinite collection of coupled random variables. This is much more complicated than a single continuous random variable, both to grasp intuitively and to construct rigorously $$\text{end quote}$$ Frankly it seems to me that you probably understand well the advanced math involved in what you're talking about here, but your are thoroughly confused about what I was proposing. Obviously no attempt would be made at what you're calling$\,\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots\,$"rigorous construction". That you would even think of such a thing perhaps indicates how you mangage to misunderstand so completely. ${}$ How do I propose to "reach" such a point. I could explain that fairly simply and I think you would understand the explanation if you read it. I wonder whether that's something you'd be willing to do?

Comment: ok, Some phone calls arrive at a switchboard at an average rate of $3.6$ per minute. The number of phone calls arriving in the first minute has a Poisson distribution with expectation $3.6.$ The number arriving in the one-and-a-half minutes after that has a Poisson distribution with expectation $5.4.$ Those two random variable are INDEPENDENT of each other because those two time periods do not overlap. THAT is how I intend to "'reach' that point." Are you really saying that's too complicated for students at this level to understand?

Comment: I suppose another aspect of how I intend to "'reach' that point" is something found in many textbooks: Suppose $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$, and now let $n\to\infty$ which $p=\lambda/n$ so that $p\to0$ which $np$ remains fixed. Then
$$
\begin{align}
& \lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr(X=x) \\ {} \\ ={}& \binom nx p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\ {} \\ ={}& \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} \left(\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-x+1)}{n^x} \right)^x\left(1-\frac\lambda n \right)^n \left(1-\frac\lambda n\right)^{-x} \\{}\\ \to{}& \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} \cdot 1\cdot e^{-\lambda}\cdot 1.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $$ \text{begin quote} $$ and what you are doing is clearly more difficult $$ \text{end quote} $$ You clearly don't have the foggiest idea what I was proposing to do. I'm amazed that you could possibly misunderstand it in such a far-fetched way.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, clearly your idea is way over my head.

Comment: I don't think it was over your head; rather I think you are in the habit of thinking about probability theory in a logically rigorous way and not of thinking of it in an elementary way. An elementary way is what I have in mind here, so it appears to me that that's why you misunderstood it.

Comment: BEGIN QUOTE which is why the Poisson process on the real line is usually constructed starting with an infinite sequence of i.i.d. exponential waiting times END QUOTE Is it you claim then, that the Poisson distribution is seldom first introduced as a certain kind of limit of binomial distributions?